# What did 'thrice defied' really mean?

Tags: harry-potter, prophecy

The prophecy states:

> "The one with the power to vanquish the Dark Lord approaches...born to those who have **thrice defied him**, born as the seventh month dies...and the Dark Lord will mark him as his equal, but he will have power the Dark Lord knows not...and either must die at the hand of the other for neither can live while the other survives...the one with the power to vanquish the Dark Lord will be born as the seventh month dies..."

What exactly does 'thrice defied him' mean?

Comment: Are you looking for the meaning of the phrase 'thrice defied him'? Or which three times the Potters/Longbottoms had 'defied him'?

Comment: This seems a bit similar to this question: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/13476/how-had-the-potters-thrice-defied-him  Are you looking for a list of the three occasions? Or a general description of what "thrice defied" means?

Comment: @AdamT I'm looking for a general description of what thrice defied him means. Does it count if you lets say escape one of his henchmen? Or do you have to turn him down?

Comment: The accepted answer in the link q details what JKR at least defines as defied: "*I mean, if you're counting, which I do, anytime you arrested one of his henchmen, anytime you escaped him, anytime you thwarted him, that's what he's looking for. And both couples qualified because they were both fighting.*"